# Mass parameters in the spontaneous symmetry breaking

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, higgs, symmetry-breaking

In [Ashok: Lectures on Quantum Field Theory](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/9812832858) Sec. 7.5 p.279 he discusses the mass parameters for the potential

$$
V = -\frac{m^2}{2}(\sigma^2+\xi^2) + \frac{\lambda}{16}(\sigma^2 + \xi^2)^2.
$$

My (pretty simple) question is the claim:

> We note that the second derivatives of the
>   potential (with respect to field variables) give the mass (squared)
>   parameters for the field operators (particles) in a theory...

I think this should come from the Taylor expansion of the potential, but I cannot see it clearly.

Answer (score 1):

Ashok should say "We note that the second derivatives of the potential with respect to field variables *computed at the minimum of the potential*  give the mass (squared) parameters for the field operators (particles) in a theory..."

Comment: (I understand the minimum part, but) Why?

Comment: You do undertstand that the Lagrangian $L= \frac 12 (\nabla \phi)^2+\frac 12 m^2 \phi^2$ has particles of mass $m$?

Comment: Don't worry, I see now Eq. (7.79), there is very clear that one of the fields do not carry mass.